# Get object from memory id?

Tags: python, memory-management, shared-memory

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(10)
id(a)
```

Here we know that id function return the identity of the object 'a'.
Suppose that we only know the id of object(139806990767008 int or long), How can I get the data from 139806990767008 returned by id function. Or get which object's id is the 139806990767008.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you need to do this?

Comment: id's can be reused after objects are deleted, so if your objects come and go, then looking them up by id can easily get you a different object than you wanted.

Comment: i need to read data from the file in different times, so i want to pass the i/o, use the data directly.

Comment: Do *not rely on this solution*.

Comment: @LiZiming how does this solve that problem? This isn't the memory address of the data *on disk*.